# How to set trackpoint sensitivity?

Tags: kde, trackpoint

Using KDE, how do I increase the sensitivity of my trackpoint? There is no trackpoint section in Systemsettings. The "Pointer speed" sliders in the Mouse and Touchpad sections don't affect it either.

`xinput set-prop 'TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint' 'libinput Accel Speed' 1` works temporarily, but the setting is reset after every hibernate/resume cycle (and possibly on other occasions).

Comment: There is an abandoned GUI `pointing-devices-kcm` which still works, otherwise see: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/faqs.html#how-do-i-configure-my-device-on-x

Comment: The `xorg.conf` solution does not work. It looks like KDE overwrites the setting for some reason even though it does not expose it. I'll try the KCM later.

Answer (score 2):

The trackpoint is stored in sysfs, under `/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio3/` (might be slightly different depending on which particular kernel and laptop you have).

You can set the sensitivity (as root) with:

```
echo 200 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio3/sensitivity
```

(replacing 200 with the desired sensitivity).

Comment: this will work, but it would have to be done every time you reboot. a script would be needed to automate it.

Answer (score 2):

The example by @mekkis works, but the change isn’t persistent. To make it permanent you can create a small bash script in `rc.local`:

### Create the script

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local` or in Fedora/RHEL/CentOS: `sudo nano /etc/rc.d/rc.local`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sudo chown $USER /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/sensitivity
echo 175 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/sensitivity

exit 0
```

1. Replace *175* with your desired sensitivity.
2. You'll have to dig around a little bit to find the exact file path for your system. It will be similar to the one used above. You are looking for a file named `sensitivity`.

The file is owned by root so the first line changes ownership to the user. The reason why our script goes into `rc.local` is because `sudo chown` isn't permanent. `rc.local` allows us to execute sudo commands on boot.

### Set as executable

`sudo chmod -v +x /etc/rc.local` or `sudo chmod -v +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local`

### Enable the service at boot:

To enable `rc.local` with systemd I would first check if it was active:

`sudo systemctl is-enabled rc-local.service`

If it returns `static` or `disabled` then enable it:

`sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service`

Reboot.

### Verify

Verify the service is running:

`sudo systemctl status rc-local.service`

Double-check that your sensitivity is changed:

`cat /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/sensitivity`

---

I tried a ton of different ways and this is what finally worked for me to keep the changes persistent.

Comment: Also, changing the mouse sensitivity does change the trackpoint sens, but this method helps keep the two separate.

Answer (score -1):

As of this writing there is no way to set TrackPoint sensitivity under Linux for at least some models.  There is no "sensitivity" option in sysfs.  However by setting the "AttrTrackpointMultiplier" value of libinput quirks, it can improve the handling of the TrackPoint.

This can easily be done by creating `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks` with contents similar to the following:

```
[Trackpoint Override]
MatchUdevType=pointingstick
MatchName=*Elan TrackPoint*
AttrTrackpointMultiplier=1.2
```

[Note that on some systems the file should be `/usr/share/libinput/local-overrides.quirks`]

Try different values of AttrTrackpointMultiplier.  One one of my systems I use "5.0" which is very high.  On other systems you might need a lower value.